# visual c++ 6.0 - rebuild all throw error C2259

Tags: visual-c++

The project was created using Visual C++ 6.0 and I'm new to using Visual C++. Now in my project, I set up Visual C++ on Windows 10, but when rebuild all below error C2259 throw. Please help me how to fix this **error C2259**. Thanks in advance.

D:\VS98\VC98\ATL\INCLUDE\atlcom.h(1827) : error C2259: 'CComObject' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members:
D:\VS98\VC98\ATL\INCLUDE\atlcom.h(1823) : while compiling class-template member function 'long __stdcall ATL::CComCreator<class ATL::CComObject >::CreateInstance(void *,const struct _GUID &,void ** )'

Comment: Visual C++6 is not supported on windows 10... or even windows XP for that matter. I'd highly suggest switching to a toolchain supported by the platform. Please note that for personal/open source use VS2019 is free.

Answer (score 0):

At last, found the issue. One of the method definitions is different.

To resolve,

- Check the function declarations and definitions prototypes in the .cpp,.h and .idl files. Also, check if they are same in all the 3 files.
- .idl file we usually miss out on modifying since the search result doesn't show the method.